# Computing $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (px)}{x}\ dx$ using $\int _0^{\infty }\:\int _0^{\infty \:}\:e^{-xy}\sin\left(px\right)\:dx\:dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

**Question:**

> By changing order of the double integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty}e^{-xy}\sin\left(px\right)\:dx\:dy$, show that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(px)}{x}\ dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ .

---

I know that by changing order of the integral, I would get,
$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty}e^{-xy}\sin\left(px\right)\:dx\:dy =\int_0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty}e^{-xy}\sin\left(px\right)\:dy\:dx$$

And by evaluating the inner integral, I would end up with $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty }\dfrac{\sin(px)}{x}\ dx$.

I know that there are ways to solve the integral $\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ but I think the question is asking something different which I'm missing. How can I show that this integral is equal to $\pi/2$ by changing the order?

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use $\int _0^{\infty}e^{-xy}\sin\left(px\right) dx=\frac p{p^2+y^2}
$ to integrate
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(px)}{x}\ dx =\int_0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty}e^{-xy}\sin\left(px\right)\:dx\:dy=\int_0^\infty \ \frac p{p^2+y^2}dy = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$